# Parsing a large excel file and writing the results back into a delimited text file

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, parsing

**Note**: Since asking *how do I?* questions on Code Review is off topic, I'll try here.

I work as an IT intern in a multinational and I was given a tedious task of combining through a 2500+ long multi-column excel report file in search of inactive servers.

Here's a sample row from that file:

[image]

Then, I got another excel file but this time with just the DB Codes (80+ of them).

My task was:

- Go through the big report file
- Find the company by its DB Code
- Check if the server is active or not active, and if not active flag it for a decommission

Of course, as you might expect, I was told to return the results in a spreadsheet in the following format:

`Full name: Acme Inc. | Code: ACM | Active?: no | Decomm?: yes`

`Fulln name:, Code:, etc.` are column headers. Here, they are just for readability.

If I were to do it manually, I'd most probably die of boredom. But! There's Python, right?

So, I exported some of the columns from the report into a tab delimited file and drafted this:

```
def read_file_to_list(file_name):
    with open(file_name, 'r') as file_handler:
        stuff = file_handler.readlines()
    return [line[:-1] for line in stuff]


def make_dic(file_name):
    with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
        rows = (line.replace('"', "").strip().split("\t") for line in f)
        return {row[0]:row[1:] for row in rows}


def search(dic, ou_codes):
    c = 1
    for k, v in dic.items():
        for code in ou_codes:
            if v[0] == code:
                print("{}. Full name: {} | Code: {} | Active?: {} | Decomm?: {}".format(c, k, *v, "yes" if v[1] == "no" else "no"))
                c += 1


decomm_codes = read_file_to_list('decomm_codes.txt')
all_of_it = make_dic('big_report.txt')

search(all_of_it, decomm_codes)
```

That spits out:

```
1. Full name: Random, Inc | Code: RNDM | Active?: yes | Decomm?: no
2. Full name: Acme Inc.| Code: ACM | Active?: no | Decomm?: yes
3. Full name: Fake Bank, Ltd.  | Code: FKBNK | Active?: yes | Decomm?: no
```

**Question:**

It looks all nice in my terminal window, but how do I write the results back into a tab-delimited text file? So it looks like this:

`Acme Inc.    ACM    no    yes`

Also, just out of curiosity, is there a way refactor the `search` method, e.g. to a one-liner? The nested list comprehensions are still on my TO-LEARN list (pun intended).

Finally, here's the contents of the `decomm_codes.txt` and `big_report.txt` files.

decomm_codes.txt:

```
RNDM
ACM
FKBNK
```

big_report.txt:

```
"Random, Inc"   RNDM    yes
Acme Inc.   ACM no
"Fake Bank, Ltd. "  FKBNK   yes
```

Comment: I can't see your pictures but why didn't you just use VLOOKUP and then Save As tab delimited?

Comment: @HarassedDad I didn't know about! I'll give it a try and see if that's what I might have needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simpy also write into a file:

```
def search(dic, ou_codes):
    c = 1
    # open a file to write to
    with open ("output.tsv","w") as outfile:
        outfile.write( "#\tFull name\tCode\tActive\tDecomm\n")
        for k, v in dic.items():
            for code in ou_codes:
                if v[0] == code:
                    # create output line
                    outputline = "{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\n".format(
                                 c, k, *v, "yes" if v[1] == "no" else "no")
                    c += 1
                    outfile.write(outputline)
                    print("{}. Full name: {} | Code: {} | Active?: {} | Decomm?: {}".format(
                          c, k, *v, "yes" if v[1] == "no" else "no"))
```